# How do I convince webpack to use the node imports over web imports when using `target: node`

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

First the code, it's a pretty silly example but it's pulled out from a more complicated github action:

#### index.js

```js
require('@octokit/rest');
console.log('hello world');
```

#### webpack.config.js

```js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  target: 'node',
  entry: './index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'index.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
};
```

#### package.json

```
{
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^4.41.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.10"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@octokit/rest": "^16.35.0"
  }
}
```

#### build command

```sh
node_modules/.bin/webpack --config webpack.config.js
```

#### running without webpack

```
$ node index.js
hello world
```

#### running after building webpack

```
$ node dist/index.js 
/tmp/x/dist/index.js:1
...

ReferenceError: navigator is not defined
    at Module.i (/tmp/x/dist/index.js:1:3659)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/tmp/x/dist/index.js:15:6701)
    at t (/tmp/x/dist/index.js:1:110)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/tmp/x/dist/index.js:15:874)
    at t (/tmp/x/dist/index.js:1:110)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/tmp/x/dist/index.js:15:697)
    at t (/tmp/x/dist/index.js:1:110)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/tmp/x/dist/index.js:1:3891)
    at t (/tmp/x/dist/index.js:1:110)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/tmp/x/dist/index.js:15:418)
```

---

## analysis

From what I've found, there's a compiled typescript package inside `node_modules` that's being imported and run here, here's some of the relevant code from the last two frames:

#### node_modules/@octokit/endpoint/dist-src/defaults.js

```js
// ...
import { getUserAgent } from "universal-user-agent";
// ...
const userAgent = `octokit-endpoint.js/${VERSION} ${getUserAgent()}`;
// ...
```

The `universal-user-agent` provides several implementations of its code in the following files:

- **node_modules/universal-user-agent/dist-node/index.js**
- **node_modules/universal-user-agent/dist-web/index.js**

As you would expect, the `dist-web` implementation uses `navigator.userAgent` -- the `node` one does something else.

---

## my current terrible workaround

I don't actually care about the user agent so I'm currently *hacking around this* with:

```sh
sed -i 's/\bnavigator\b/({})/g' dist/index.js
```

yes, running `sed` to eliminate accesses to `navigator`

---

## tl;dr

How do I convince webpack to pick the `dist-node` implementation over the `dist-web` one (like `require(...)` seems to do when running `node` directly)?

Comment: Well it's strange because looking at the source of `universal-user-agent` it should only use the browser version if in fact you are targeting the browser (which clearly you aren't). You appear to be bundling your `node_modules`, is that intentional? If not, it could be the issue, try using [webpack-node-externals](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-node-externals) to exclude these when bundling.

Comment: @James my entire reproduction is in the question :)

Comment: based on your comment I presume you aren't _intentionally_ bundling the node modules, therefore you should make sure to exclude bundling non-native modules (such as `octokit`). As per my comment above, this can be done using the `webpack-node-externals` library. I'm presuming this is the issue as when you bundle lines like `require('lib')` change due to webpack having to use it's own module loader, if you can try it out and let me know if it works I can post this as an answer.

Comment: I'm intentionally bundling `octokit`, yes

Comment: Why are you bundling backend code  you don't really stand to gain much in that respect. Have you tried what I have suggested to rule it out?

Comment: it's not really important to the question, but I don't want to check in the entirety of `node_modules` which is the alternative (github actions does not install dependencies before running and runs from a git repository)

Comment: well it's important if bundling the library is what's causing the problem, and if you are doing so unnecessarily ‍♂️ I can see from the answer posted below it looks like a bug in the lib you are using (which makes sense), given the simple answer was to just suggest using `resolve` in webpack to change the main file I was wondering if bundling was the problem and whether you could just avoid bundling altogether (if it wasn't necessary)

Comment: "why is this broken?" "don't do that" is not an answer

Comment: that's why it's a comment and not an answer. You'd have been easier just replying to my first comment by saying "I want to know why the library doesn't do what it should" because you don't seem open to ways of circumventing the problem. Just to clarify though, "don't do that" *can* be the answer, particularly when performing an unnecessary task is conducive to the problem. If you just want to understand why a lib is broken then maybe you should've just raised an issue on GitHub than asking a question on here ‍♂️

Comment: Again, the entire information is pretty clear in the question

Answer (score 8):

It's a known issue for [@octokit/rest](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@octokit/rest): https://github.com/octokit/rest.js/issues/1485

There is also a long discussion in this [universal-user-agent](https://github.com/gr2m/universal-user-agent) issue: https://github.com/gr2m/universal-user-agent/issues/23

There seems to be a permanent fix, but not released yet. Until then you can try 2 things to resolve the `dist-node` of `universal-user-agent` using [Webpack Resolve](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/):

#### 1) Using `alias` to resolve the `dist-node`

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  target: 'node',
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'universal-user-agent': path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/universal-user-agent/dist-node/index.js')
    }
  },
  entry: './index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'index.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
};
```

#### 2) Using `mainFields`

```
module.exports = {
  target: 'node',
  resolve: {
    mainFields: ['main', 'module']
  },
  entry: './index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'index.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
};
```

You should go with the first method, because the second one reflects to all `node_modules` and you'll run into issues sooner or later.

#### Webpack issue

There seems to be an issue and a long discussion about this problem here: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/5756

Comment: Can you link the webpack bug?  Presumably not following `node`'s module lookup while having `target: 'node'` is the actual root cause?

Comment: I don't think this is a webpack bug, but it is related how webpack and pika define `module` behavior. `universal-user-agent` uses [`@pika/pack`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@pika/pack) and [`@pika/plugin-build-node`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@pika/plugin-build-node) to build the package and `pika` defines `"module": "dist-web/index.js"` inside `node_modules/universal-user-agent/package.json`. This also happens with rollup as you can read [here](https://github.com/gr2m/universal-user-agent/issues/23#issuecomment-539175974), so I believe it has to do on how pika maps the generated files.

Comment: Please read these comments [here](https://github.com/gr2m/universal-user-agent/issues/23#issuecomment-538776088) and [here](https://github.com/gr2m/universal-user-agent/issues/23#issuecomment-556406953). *Node apps work perfectly fine, because node apps respect the "main" key. The "module" key is not used by Node*

Comment: I have read those, surely webpack should be using the same approach as node apps when using `target: node` right?

Comment: Yes, I too believe that should be the proper behavior. And it looks like there is a lot of discussion about this issue here https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/5756

Comment: cool, that sounds like the actual root cause problem -- could you include that in your answer (comments on SO are pretty ephemeral and may be deleted)

Comment: Yes, maybe it is. There are a lot of opinions onto that discussion and it also seems rollup has this behavior as well. Just added the webpack issue to my answer.